# How to get a script to activate on modal load?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have a modal that is prepopulated with some text for the user to edit, with a limit of 500 characters.  I wanted to include a 'remaining character' notification.  I have it working for the onKeyUp, but I want it to initialize with how many characters are left (right now the span is empty until the user hits a key).  Neither of the onLoad functions are working (maybe onLoad is wrong?  Fairly new here).  Any help is appreciated!

```
<div id="tooltip-modal" style="display:none">   
    <script language = "Javascript">
    maxLength = 500;
    var container = $("#tooltip_body");

    function taCount(tooltipBody,Cnt) { 
        objCnt = createObject(Cnt);
        objVal = tooltipBody.value;
        if (objCnt) {
            objCnt.innerText=maxLength-objVal.length;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function createObject(objId) {
        if (document.getElementById) return document.getElementById(objId);
        else if (document.layers) return eval("document." + objId);
        else if (document.all) return eval("document.all." + objId);
        else return eval("document." + objId);
    }
    onLoad="alert('Loaded')";
    onLoad="return taCount(container,'myCounter')";
    </script>

    <body>
    <form method="post" action="#" id="update-tooltip">
        <h2>Edit the description of this item:</h2>
        <input type="hidden" name="tooltip_id" id="tooltip_id">
        <textarea onKeyUp="return taCount(this,'myCounter')" name="tooltip_body" id="tooltip_body" class="input" rows=7 wrap="physical" cols=40></textarea>
        <br><br>

        You have <strong><span id="myCounter" ></span></strong> characters remaining for your description...</h3><br>
        <button type="submit" value="Update" id="update" >Update</button>
    </form>
</body>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that onload has to be tied to an element on the page, such as the body tag.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too; I had it in the body tag, but it didn't work there either.

Comment: Like this?  <body onLoad="alert('Loaded')" >